# Reading data from Firebase and iterate trough List of type Courses in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieve data from Firebase and I need to display only an attribute from the given data. For example, I have the class Courses that has 3 attributes(courseTitle, courseTeacher, courseDetails).

```
export class Courses {
    courseTitle:string;
    courseTeacher: string;
    courseDetails: string;
    constructor(courseTitle:string,courseTeacher: string,courseDetails: string){
        this.courseTitle=courseTitle;
        this.courseTeacher=courseTeacher;
        this.courseDetails=courseDetails;

    }
}
```

Beside this I have the Course Service that drags data from Firebase.

```
export class CoursesService {
  courses$:any;
  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.courses$ = this.db.list<Courses>('/Courses').valueChanges();
   }
  
  getCourses():Observable<Courses[]>
  {
    return this.courses$;
  }
}
```

Now I have the StudentHomePageComponent where I want to get the List from Course Service.

```
export class StudentHomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: Observable<Courses[]>;

  constructor(public coursesService: CoursesService,public afAuth:AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courses=this.coursesService.getCourses();    
  }
  generateArray(obj:any){
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
 }
 logout():void
 {
    this.afAuth.signOut();
 }

}
```

I also have the StudentHomePageComponent HTML where I want to iterate trough the courses and display in different divs the name of the teacher, or the details from the course.

```
<div class="big_card" >
    
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of courses">
        <div class="card-course-title" >
          {{item.courseTitle}}
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="button-course" (click)="checkCourse()">Check</button>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I receive the error "Type 'Observable<Courses[]>' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'." in the HTML file when I try to iterate trough the list of type Courses.
What would be the best way to drag data from Firebase and handle them as an array of type Courses, where I can access certain attributes from the class.?

Comment: Maybe easier if you actually post what data you’re getting back

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MikeOne I renewed my question, hope this will be more understandable.

Comment: Try *ngFor="let item of courses | async”